# stop bootstrap carousel next prev button work on outer div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is the code of carousel

next prev button work on his below div how to stop it

when i click the below div carousel work as usual move

bellow the carousel div have another with tabing system when i click on any tab then carousel slide moving on usually i want to stop it .i think its overlapping div

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" style=" border-top: 4px solid #ccc;">
            <div class="carousel-inner" style=" margin-top: 20px;">
                <div class="item active ">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                           <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                          <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                           <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            
                           <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                             <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                  </div><!-- /Slide1 --> 
             
            </div>
            
           
        <nav>
       <ul class="control-box pager" >
        <li><a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
        <li><a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
        <!-- /.control-box -->   
                                  
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were just missing a few pieces of bootstrap syntax. I just did a side-by-side comparison of your code to

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Does the below work?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" style=" border-top: 4px solid #ccc;">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style=" margin-top: 20px;">
                <div class="item active ">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                           <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                          <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                           <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            
                           <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                             <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thosmes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                  </div><!-- /Slide1 --> 
              <div class="item ">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                           <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                          <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                           <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            
                           <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thomes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                             <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-xs-12 ">
              <div class="fff">
                                                         <div class="caption">
             
                                                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                                                     
                                                                        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                                                                        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> Alxender Thosmes</strong><br>
              Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
             <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
            </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                  </div><!-- /Slide2 --> 
             
            </div>
           
        <nav>
       <ul class="control-box pager" >
        <li><a data-slide="prev" role="button" href="#myCarousel" class="left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
        <li><a data-slide="next" role="button" href="#myCarousel" class="right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
        <!-- /.control-box -->   
                                  
        </div>
```

Comment: does not work for me i test it work as it is same when i paste your code in project

Comment: @Abbbaskhan My mistake I misunderstood at first, you were saying your issue was when you press on one of the arrows left or right it would continue scrolling afterwards? Edited code to fix that.

Comment: actually i have three container of template first container contain menu   second contain caruosel slider and third have tabing system when i click tabing button then move start caruosel slider

Comment: when i click the tabbing area  then carousel start sliding i want to stop this when i click left right button then start moving  .i think carousel container overlap on the the tabing container

Comment: @Abbbaskhan I'm having a lot of trouble recreating this issue you're talking about